# is it possible to get ieee: float "bits" from javascript number?

Tags: javascript, math, binary

I want to write out to, and read in ieee format float/double values from a binary byte stream in a javascript module.  Anyone know of how one would go about doing this?   an equivalent to the doubleToRawLongBits and longBitsToDouble functionality in java.

Comment: Maybe you can use float64 typed arrays and access the raw data, or something like this. But no idea, I have never used typed arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) for such things. Store your doubles into a [`Float64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array), then access the raw bytes from the underlying [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) (and use bit shifts on those if you need single bits). If you're doing something more complicated, want to mix multiple types, or even control the endianness, overlay it with a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).